# Rotating an animated model

Tags: animation, rigging, eevee-render-engine, keyframes, axis

I was just busy finishing my animation when I noticed in my camera view from the beginning, the model itself was shifted slightly off course from facing perpendicular to the x axis (I used orthographic view to get a better representation of how it looks like). How do I fix the rotation of the model without screwing up the animation itself? Thanks.[image]

Comment: You could parent the object to an empty, move the keyframes to the empty, and then rotate the object.

Comment: It is also quite possible could be as simple as clearing transform on rig object. Hard to tell from information given, ...

Answer (score 2):

You can create an Empty at the pivot of your model's armature, parent the armature to the Empty and rotate the Empty.

Or you can move whole rotation keys of your model's Root (Hip) bone in Graph Editor.

Comment: omg it actually worked tysm! I parented the rig object to the empty and it doesn't affect the animation anymore, really appreciate the help!